# Restrict execution of xsl:template to specified number of times

Tags: xml, xslt, loops

Here's my XSLT:

```
<!-- Looping through both Items and Categories of Items -->
<xsl:for-each select="statement">

    <!-- Define whether current node is a single item or a category of items -->
    <xsl:choose>

        <!-- Category of items -->
        <xsl:when test="statement">

            <!-- Render all items in this category -->
            <xsl:for-each select="statement">
                <xsl:call-template name="renderItem" select="current()" />
            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:when>

        <!-- Single item -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="renderItem" select="." />
        </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to be able to output specific number of items, but not all of them.
How do I make "renderItem" to be executed not more than, say, 4 times?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks pretty odd: all this xsl:choose, xsl:for-each, and xsl:call-template looks like a home-made implementation of apply-templates and template rules. Moreover, xsl:call-template does not take a select attribute - that's a syntax error and your XSLT processor should flag it as such, not simply ignore it.

Ignoring that, I think the simplest solution to your problem is to test whether you want to process an item by examining its position in the tree. Something like

```
<xsl:template match="statement">
  <xsl:variable name="pos">
    <xsl:number level="any" from="..."/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="$pos &lt; 5">...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Michael, this a pseudocode not the real thing, so, you are right, it won't work most likely. Thank you for posting your solution, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for your problem relies on using recursion, controlling manually the number of times that the template is executed (or counting the number of times that items are rendered).

It is more of an idea of how to implement it than a solution to your problem (I do not know how your XML file looks like), but I have tried to adapt the code that you posted (maybe incorrectly, without the XML I am not sure).

```
<xsl:template match="renderItems">
    <!-- Set of items to process -->
    <xsl:param name="items" />
    <!-- Tracks number of times that this template is going to be executed -->
    <xsl:param name="count" />

    <!-- Check if we have available executions -->
    <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
        <!-- Define whether the current node is a single item or a category of items -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Category of items -->
            <xsl:when test="$items/statement">
                <!-- Select the number of items which are going to be rendered taking into
                     account the count parameter -->
                <xsl:variable name="items-to-render"
                              select="$items/statement[position() &lt;=$count]" />
                <!-- Render item in this category -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$items-to-render">
                    <!-- 
                        Do whatever you have to do with each item
                    -->
                </xsl:for-each>
                <!-- Call this template again with the updated values -->
                <xsl:call-template name="renderItems">
                    <!-- Remove the category of items from the items to be processed -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="items"
                                    select="$items[position() > 1]" />
                    <!-- Extract from the count, the number of items that we already processed -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="count"
                                    select="$count - count($items-to-render)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- Single item -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Render this item -->
                <!--
                    Do whatever you have to do with each item
                -->
                <!-- Call this template again with the updated values -->
                <xsl:call-template name="renderItems">
                    <!-- Remove this item from the items to be processed -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="items"
                                    select="$items[position() > 1]" />
                    <!-- One item less to process -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="count"
                                    select="$count - 1" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>       
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Then you can call the template using (or something alike).

```
<xsl:call-template name="renderItems">
    <xsl:with-param name="items"
                    select="statement" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Pablo, thank you for posting this solution. I'll give it a try.